# Directionality of Mediation Effect

Tags: regression, causality, mediation

Is it possible to (statistically) determine the directionality of a mediation effect, i.e. $X \rightarrow M \rightarrow Y$ vs. $X \rightarrow Y \rightarrow M$ for example, or is this purely based on theoretical considerations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some cases, one can (quasi)experimentally test the causality between variables.

However without such intervention in data, statistics is helpless, and correlation is mere correlation. Without further theoretical assumptions nothing can be done.